# Trying to remove commas from Long numbers in Grails application

Tags: grails, gsp

I have this code:

```
    <g:link action="edit" id="${testObjectResults.id}">
               ${fieldValue(bean: testObjectResults, field: "id")}
   </g:link>
```

the links is creating links, ID numbers, with commas in them; I do not want the commas.
I tried this.

```
   <g:link action="edit" id="${testObjectResults.id}">
          <g:formatNumber number="${fieldValue(bean: testObjectResults, field: "id")}"
                     type="number" minIntegerDigits="1" />
   </g:link>
```

But that did not work.  I am using Grails 2.3.9.  I have tried stuff from this page: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.9/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fieldValue` format the number itself so try this

```
<g:link action="edit" id="${testObjectResults.id}">
    ${testObjectResults?.id}
</g:link>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have 3 options here:

1. specify the `@format`:

   `<g:formatNumber number="${number}" type="number" format="######"/>`
2. specify the `@locale` which doesn't use the group separation:

   `<g:formatNumber number="${number}" type="number" locale="${Locale.GERMANY}"/>`
3. set default `Locale` (that doesn't use group separation) for the whole application to get rid of commas everywhere

Comment: Or `<g:formatNumber number="${number}" type="number" groupingUsed="false"/>`